# After Click on Print Page, Css differ from real page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

This is my code to print:

```
<div id="printthis">
  <?php if(isset($_POST['p_id'])){
      $p_id=trim($_POST['p_id']);
      $select="select * from `bed_allotment` WHERE `p_id`='$p_id'";
      $q=mysqli_query($mysqli,$select);
      $bedCount = mysqli_num_rows($q);
        if ($bedCount <= 0) {
            echo "No Data Found";
            return;
        }
      $row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($q);
      $checkin_date=$row1['checkin_date'];
      $tmpDTVar = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $checkin_date);
      $tmpDTVar = $tmpDTVar->format('Y-m-d');
      $checkout_date=date('Y-m-d');
      $dateVar1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $tmpDTVar);
      $dateVar2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $checkout_date);
      $interval = $dateVar1->diff($dateVar2);
      $totalAmt = 0;
      $sql = "select bed_allotment.room_id,bed_allotment.bed_id,bed_allotment.checkin_date,bed_allotment.p_id,room_info.room_id,room_info.rate_per_day, room_info.room_type FROM bed_allotment
        INNER JOIN room_info ON room_info.room_id=bed_allotment.room_id Where `bed_allotment`.p_id='$p_id' order by checkin_date asc";
      $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->execute();
      $ctr=$stmt->rowCount();
      if ($ctr > 0) {
      $roomid_arr= array();
      $roomid_name_arr= array();
      $bedid_arr= array();
      $dates_arr= array();
      $days_arr = array();
      $times_arr = array();
      $RoomRatesID = array();
      $RoomRatesRate = array();
      while($row= $stmt->fetch()) {
        array_push($roomid_arr,$row['room_id']);
        array_push($roomid_name_arr,$row['room_type']);
        array_push($bedid_arr,$row['bed_id']);
        array_push($dates_arr,$row['checkin_date']);
    }
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        for ($i = 1; $i <= count($dates_arr); $i++) {
            $tmpfrom = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',$dates_arr[$i - 1]); 
            //var_dump($tmpfrom) ;
            if($i == count($dates_arr))
                $tmpTo = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
            else
                $tmpTo = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',$dates_arr[$i]);
                $tmpDT = $tmpfrom->diff($tmpTo);
            array_push($days_arr, $tmpDT->days);
            array_push($times_arr, $tmpDT->h);
        }
        if (count($roomid_arr) <= 0) {
            echo "No Data";
            return;
        }
        if (in_array($row['room_id'],$roomid_arr)) {
          array_push($RoomRatesID, $row['room_id']);
          array_push($RoomRatesRate, $row['rate_per_day']);
        }
    }
    if($bedCount <= 0) {
      echo '
          <div id="tow" style="display: none;">';
    } else {
      echo '
        <div id="tow" style="display: block;">';
    }
?></div>
```

And This is function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printDiv(divName) {
        var divToPrint = document.getElementById(divName);
        var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=1024,height=700');
        popupWin.document.open();
        popupWin.document.write('<html><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/print.css" type="text/css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"><body onload="window.print()">' + divToPrint.innerHTML +' </html>');
        popupWin.document.close();
        window.close();
    }
    function showDiv() {
        document.getElementById('tow').style.display = "block";
    }
</script>
```

I have only use display:none in print.css and remaining css is coming from main style.css.
What should i do?? Please help me. Where I am going wrong.

Comment: `$p_id=trim($_POST['p_id']); $select="select * from bed_allotment WHERE p_id='$p_id'";` your code is vulnerable to SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

You need to add media="print" if you want your css to impact the printed version of the page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/print.css" type="text/css" media="print">
```

Have you tried this?

Comment: yes i used two css 
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/print.css' media="print" />